# How to compare two lists of strings whose elements patially match

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

I have this two lists:

```
list_y= ['aaa/bbb/ccc/18_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_14_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_14_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_16_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/14_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_17_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_19_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_17_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_18_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/15_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/12_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_16_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/16_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_15_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/17_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/13_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_13_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/18_12_13_y_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_15_13_y_n']

list_x= ['aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_13_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_14_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_17_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/14_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_19_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/12_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_14_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_16_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_18_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/17_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_15_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_17_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_15_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/11_12_16_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/16_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/18_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/15_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/13_12_13_x_n', 'aaa/bbb/ccc/18_12_13_x_n']
```

I want to compare if they have the same strings (except for the x or y letters) and then I want to know if each string in list_x is in the same position as its correspondent string in list_y

This is what I've tried:

```
list_a.sort()
list_b.sort()
list_a[0][0:21] == list_b[0][0:21]
```

This return True, because I'm comparing the first 22 elements of each string, and that's fine, the problem is that in this way I'm doing it only for the first string in the lists. How to do it for the whole lists?

To summarize my doubts:

- How to compare two lists of strings that just partially match?
- I use the list_a[0][0:21] == list_b[0][0:21] to compare the first 22 elements of the strings, but is there a way to 'exclude' the x and y and compare the whole string?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh yes, if they have the same caracters at the beginning it shouldn't matter, thanks for that

Comment: Sorry, I read wrongly. I'm sorting because the strings in both lists have the same elements (same letters) before the x or the y, so sorting put them in same position, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use zip-function and for-loop:

```
for a_string, b_string in zip(list_a, list_b):
    if a_string[0:21] == b_string[0:21]:
        print("a_string anf b_string are partially identical")
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to exclude the "x" or "y" and compare the whole strings (not taking the first 22 elements)?

Comment: The short but nasty approach would be something like this:
`a_string[:i] + a_string [i+1:] == b_string[:i] + b_string [i+1:]` where i is the index of your x/y

Comment: Another imo more elegant solution could look something like this:  
`a_split = a_string.split('y')` This splits a_string along every 'y' and makes a list with the remaining string parts  
`a_joined = ''.join(a_split)` This puts all the previously split elements back into one string, but without the 'y's.  
Do the same thing with b_string, then you can compare the two

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the length of the lists is the same (len(list_x)==len(list_y)) and all sort operation is done...

**Variant 1** compare strings without 21-s symbol

```
length_x=len(list_x)
for i in range(0,length_x):
    if list_x[i][0:21] == list_y[i][0:21] and list_x[i][22:]==list_y[i][22:]:
        print 'Strings are equal at pos: %d' % i #countdown starts from 0
```

**Variant 2** compare strings without x and y symbols. x and y removed by regexp in whole string

```
import re
length_x=len(list_x)

for i in range(0,length_x):
    if re.sub('[xy]','',list_x[i])==re.sub('[xy]','',list_y[i]):
        print 'Strings are equal at pos: %d' % i #countdown starts from 0
```

results

```
Strings are equal at pos: 4
Strings are equal at pos: 9
```

Comment: Please amend your answer to detail what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

This would test for both and print result of both condition

```
list_x.sort()
list_y.sort()

list_x_mod = []
list_y_mod = []

for i in list_x:
    list_x_mod.append(i[0:21])

for i in list_y:
    list_y_mod.append(i[0:21])

index = 0
while index < len(list_x_mod):
    if list_x_mod[index] in list_y_mod:
        print("Item", index, "in list_x exist in list_y")
    if list_x_mod[index] == list_y_mod[index]:
        print("Item", index, "is in same position on both list")
    index += 1
```

This would test even if they are not in the same position.